# Language translation comment handling

Tags: antlr4, visitor-pattern, stringtemplate

I am writing a translator using antlr 4 and string templates. I have put the comments on a separate channel, and am using the visitor pattern to pass the templates around. I now want to output the comments in the translated code. Does anyone have any suggestions about the easiest way of doing this?

One idea I had was to create a comment template which would hold any comments and the template from lower level visitors. However this means I will need to add a check for comments in each visitor method.

Comment: There're not enough details for a funded suggestion, but one thing to consider is that the token stream can give you all tokens, including those not on the default channel. They come with their original position, which you could use to copy them over to the new target place.